# Vispy multiple graphs

Tags: python, glsl, vispy

I'm fairly new to python programming and I'm struggling with the Vispy Library.

Basically, I have a Raspberry pi connected to 2 Arduinos accelerometers sensors. The raspberry is sending the X, Y and Z values from both of the sensors through UDP to my computer. Then my computer has to displays 9 graphs : 6 for the evolutions of x, y and z for both sensors and 3 for the differences between them (X1-X2, Y1-Y2 and Z1-Z2) and finally, it must be in real-time.

I wanted to use the Vispy library for that last point. After reading the documentation, I came up with the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from vispy import app
from vispy import gloo
import socket
from itertools import count

# init x, y arrays
x1_vals = []
time_vals = []

#UDP connection from Raspberry pi
UDP_IP = ""
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

# Initialize the index and set it to 1
index = count()
next(index)

# Initialize the Canvas c
c = app.Canvas(keys='interactive')

vertex = """
attribute vec2 a_position;
void main (void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
"""

fragment = """
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 10.0);
}
"""
program = gloo.Program(vertex, fragment)

@c.connect
def on_resize(event):
    gloo.set_viewport(0, 0, *event.size)

@c.connect
def on_draw(event):
    gloo.clear((1,1,1,1))
    program.draw('line_strip')


def on_timer(event):
    
    # next index
    cpt = next(index)
    
    # Get data from UDP
    recv, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    data = recv.decode('UTF-8').split(';')
    
    # We want to display only 100 samples so the graph still readable.
    # So we delete the first value of the x array if there are more than 100 values
    if (cpt > 100):
        del x1_vals[0]
        time_vals = np.linspace(-1.0, +1.0, 100)      
    else:
        time_vals = np.linspace(-1.0, +1.0, cpt)

    # The values must be bound between -1.0 and 1.0
    tmp = float(data[0])*0.5
    if (tmp >= 1):
        tmp = float(0.99)
    elif (tmp <= -1):
        tmp = float(-0.99)
    
    x1_vals.append(tmp)
    
    # Then we concatenate the arrays of x and y
    program['a_position'] = np.c_[time_vals, x1_vals].astype(np.float32)
    c.update()
   
c.timer = app.Timer('auto', connect=on_timer, start=True)
    
c.show()
app.run()
```

So as the comments describe it, it firstly intitializes the UDP connection and the canvas, then for each values received it updates the canvas with the newly added value. If the number of values exceed 100, the first value of the array is deleted to keep a constant number of samples.

It works well when I want to display only the X1 accelerometer sensors evolution. So now I picked [the code from the Vispy documentation which demonstrates how to show multiple graphs](https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/master/examples/demo/gloo/realtime_signals.py), but the code is a bit too complex for my level.

Basically, in my code I receive all the sensors values in the `data` array. I pick the first value [0] (X1), but the complete data looks like this : `[x1, y1, z1, dx, dy, dz, x2, y2, z2]` where dx = x1 - x2, dy = y1 - y2 and dz = z1 - z2. (the difference has to be directly calculated on the raspberry).

So I tried to modify the code from the documentation as following :

```
# Number of cols and rows in the table.
nrows = 3
ncols = 3

# Number of signals.
m = nrows*ncols

# Number of samples per signal.
n = 100
```

Because I want 9 graphs and only 100 samples per graph.

I ignored the index, the color and deleted the amplitude has it is not required in my case. Basically, I almost kept the original code for the whole setting part, then I replaced the `def on_timer` with mine.

Now I'm trying to feed the `a_position` array from GLSL with my own data. But I'm not sure how to prepare the data to make it works properly with this code. I'm struggling to understand what does these lines do :

```
# GLSL C code
VERT_SHADER = """
    // Compute the x coordinate from the time index.
    float x = -1 + 2*a_index.z / (u_n-1);
    vec2 position = vec2(x - (1 - 1 / u_scale.x), a_position);
    // Find the affine transformation for the subplots.
    vec2 a = vec2(1./ncols, 1./nrows)*.9;
    vec2 b = vec2(-1 + 2*(a_index.x+.5) / ncols,
                  -1 + 2*(a_index.y+.5) / nrows);
    // Apply the static subplot transformation + scaling.
    gl_Position = vec4(a*u_scale*position+b, 0.0, 1.0);
"""

# Python code
def __init__(self):
    self.program['a_position'] = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    
def on_timer(self, event):
    k = 10
    y[:, :-k] = y[:, k:]
    y[:, -k:] = amplitudes * np.random.randn(m, k)

    self.program['a_position'].set_data(y.ravel().astype(np.float32))
```

I deleted the surrounding code that I think I'm understanding.

Note that even if I'm starting with python, I'm aware that they are using a class definition for the Canvas when I'm using the bare object in my code. I understand the use of `self` and others.

How can I adapt the code from the realtime_signals documentation to my case ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Overall that realtime signals example is, in my opinion, a bit of a hack. It "cheats" to produce as many plots as it does, but in the end the result is fast.

What that bit of shader code is doing is trying to take the series of line vertices and figure out which "sub-plot" they should go in. All vertices of all the lines are going into the shader as one array. The shader code is trying to say "this vertex is 23rd in the array which means it must belong to sub-plot 5 and it is the 3rd point in that plot because we know we have 5 points per plot" (as an example). The shader does this mostly by the information in `a_index`. For example, this bit:

```
    // Compute the x coordinate from the time index.
    float x = -1 + 2*a_index.z / (u_n-1);
    vec2 position = vec2(x - (1 - 1 / u_scale.x), a_position);
```

Is adjusting the x coordinate (a_position) based on which sub-plot the point falls in.

The next chunk:

```
    // Find the affine transformation for the subplots.
    vec2 a = vec2(1./ncols, 1./nrows)*.9;
    vec2 b = vec2(-1 + 2*(a_index.x+.5) / ncols,
                  -1 + 2*(a_index.y+.5) / nrows);
    // Apply the static subplot transformation + scaling.
    gl_Position = vec4(a*u_scale*position+b, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Is trying to determine how big each subplot should be. So the first chunk was "what subplot does this point fall in" and this one is "where in that subplot does the point sit". This code it coming up with a linear affine transformation (y = m*x + b) to scale the line to the appropriate size so that all the subplots are the same size and don't overlap.

I'm not sure I can go into more detail without re-walking the whole script and trying to understand exactly what each value in `a_index` is.

**Edit**: Another suggestion, in the long run you may want to move the UDP recv code to a separate thread (QThread if using a Qt backend) that emits a signal with the new data when it is available. This way the GUI/main thread stays responsive and isn't hung up waiting for data to come in.